# cannot find fat32 efi partition while installing Apricity Os

Tags: linux, arch-linux, system-installation

I created a bootable usb of apricity os and tried to dual-boot with windows 10.i came upon this problem [image]

as you can see there isnt any efi partition.what should i do?

Comment: make an EFI partition? You're inside gparted, a disk partitioner.  Seriously, you will need to provide more info, e.g. do you have data you want to keep on that disk? (in that case you probably should not be installing a new OS without a backup).

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type
`sudo parted /dev/sda print` . 
Check your partition table . 
If it's **not** gpt check if all four of your disks are of type primary . If they are all primary , you may want to follow [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/245610/how-to-check-if-a-disk-uses-gpt-or-mbr-and-how-to-convert-between-the-two/) guide or use any software to reduce the number of primary partitions . Once you are done with the process follow the following process -

Step 1 - Click on create after selecting "Free Space" .

Step 2 - Reduce the size of the partition by aroung 300 MB and select file system ext4 .

Step 3 - Select the newly created free space and select fat32 file system , flag it as esp and mount it to /boot/efi .
Now you should be able to install Apricity OS .